# How to hide pin to taskbar for an electron app

Tags: electron, taskbar

The Pin to taskbar option is creating issues with my electron app.

I would like to know how to disable the right click of a electron app in the  *Windows Taskbar*.
I don't want to show the entire options while right clicking my electron app.

[image: Windows Taskbar Options of an electron app]

Comment: What kind of issues do you observe?

Comment: pin to taskbar is pinning electron, not the actual app. I thought its easy for me to remove the task bar options or atleast "Pin to taskbar" and Electron options except Close Window.